# Download a pdf file from a website that requires log in using requests, python3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a website that I want to download a pdf using request, the website requires you to log in then you can access the pdf file.

I am using this script but it isn't working, what is the problem? I used some code from another post, but couldn't figure out how to resolve this issue!!!

```
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'
}


login_data = {
    'Email': 'My-email',
    'Password': 'My-password',
    'login': 'Login'
}


url = 'https://download-website' #The website i want to download the file from
filename = 'filename.pdf'
# creating a connection to the pdf
print("Creating the connection ...")


with requests.session() as s:
    url1 = 'https://login-website/' #The website i want to log in into
    r = s.get(url1, headers=headers, stream=True)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    login_data['__RequestVerificationToken'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name':'__RequestVerificationToken'})['value']

    r = s.post(url1, data=login_data, headers=headers, stream=True)
    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    
        if r.status_code != 200:
            print("Could not download the file '{}'\nError Code : {}\nReason : {}\n\n".format(
                url, r.status_code, r.reason), file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            # Storing the file as a pdf
            print("Saving the pdf file  :\n\"{}\" ...".format(filename))
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                try:
                    total_size = int(r.headers['Content-length'])
                    saved_size_pers = 0
                    moversBy = 8192*100/total_size
                    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
                        if chunk:
                            f.write(chunk)
                            saved_size_pers += moversBy
                            print("\r=>> %.2f%%" % (
                                saved_size_pers if saved_size_pers <= 100 else 100.0), end='')
                    print(end='\n\n')
                except Exception:
                    print("==> Couldn't save : {}\\".format(filename))
                    f.flush()
                    r.close()
            r.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, because I do not know the link to the website. Try to write the keys of the user data in lower case. If that doesn't work try to find out what the registration form of the website expects with the developer tools of your browser.